# Python Tkinter independent updates

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a simple application that allows you to draw in a canvas but also have a timer count how long you have been drawing. I got the application to allow me to draw and display the time but I have no idea how to have the timer update while drawing in the canvas.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you have so far? This problem is likely to be solvable using the tkinter `.after` method to schedule a function to be called periodically to update the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import time.time
from threading import Timer

# for further usage keep your label in a global variable / class attribute
# _timer_label = 

def update_timer():
    _time_label.set(str(time.time()))
    new_timer = Timer(30.0, update_timer)
    new_timer.start()
```

You need to call update timer once after you have configured your label variable and it will keep running.

As a side note, when you ask a question on StackOverflow try to give context, and code of what you tried.